# Adding custom end points, No error line

Tags: plugin-development, wpdb, rest-api, api, wp-api

I have been trying to implement a custom end point that inserts data from my mobile application into this database. However, I cant seem to find the correct way to do it. Some places used #wpdp->insert, while others used

$wpdb->get_results($query)  and query would be "INSERT INTO 'wp_woocommerce_vendor' .....

none has worked for me. I get an error

There has been a critical error on your website.

Learn more about debugging in WordPress.

if possible, is there a way for me to check responses? such as, if insert is succesfull.
return $data['status']='Database added Successfully.';

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'my_register_route' );

function my_register_route() {
    register_rest_route( 'my-route', 'my-phrase', array(
                    'methods' => 'POST',
                    'callback' => 'custom_phrase',
                )
            );
}

function custom_phrase() {

  global $wpdb;
    $data = array();

    $parameters = $request_data->get_params();
    $vendor_vendor_id = $parameters['vendor_vendor_id'];
    $vendor_product_id = $parameters['vendor_product_id'];
    $vendor_product_name = $parameters['vendor_product_name'];
    $vendor_product_qty = $parameters['vendor_product_qty'];
    $vendor_product_unit_price = $parameters['vendor_product_unit_price'];
    $vendor_product_amount = $parameters['vendor_product_amount'];
    $vendor_percent = $parameters['vendor_percent'];
    $vendor_amount = $parameters['vendor_amount'];
    $vendor_order_id = $parameters['vendor_order_id'];
    $vendor_order_date = $parameters['vendor_order_date'];
    $vendor_send_money_status = $parameters['vendor_send_money_status'];
    $vendor_send_money_date = $parameters['vendor_send_money_date'];
    $vendor_product_delivared = $parameters['vendor_product_delivared'];

    $table = 'wp_woocommerce_vendor';
    $data = array(
      'vendor_vendor_id' => $vendor_vendor_id,
      'vendor_product_id' => $vendor_product_id,
      'vendor_product_name' => $vendor_product_name,
      'vendor_product_qty' => $vendor_product_qty,
      'vendor_product_unit_price' => $vendor_product_unit_price,
      'vendor_product_amount' => $vendor_product_amount,
      'vendor_percent' => $vendor_percent,
      'vendor_amount' => $vendor_amount,
      'vendor_order_id' => $vendor_order_id,
      'vendor_order_date' => $vendor_order_date,
      'vendor_send_money_status' => $vendor_send_money_status,
      'vendor_send_money_date' => $vendor_send_money_date,
      'vendor_product_delivared' => $vendor_product_delivared
    );
    $wpdb->insert( $table, $data );

    $data['status']='Database added Successfully.';
    return rest_ensure_response( 'Hello World! This is my first REST API' );
}
```

Sources:
https://www.tychesoftwares.com/creating-custom-api-endpoints-in-the-wordpress-rest-api/
https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

function custom_phrase($request_data)

$request_data was missing.

Fixed it :)

Comment: Note that the database insert may have not succeeded, so you can do `$data['status'] = $wpdb->insert_id ? 'success' : 'error';` or something like that. :) Also, please format code in your post. That would make it more readable or easier for people to notice. ;)

Comment: Thanks! then i just return $data right?

Comment: Yes, that's right, but it's up to you on what data should be returned.